# Is there any way in Laravel or Jquery so that I can prevent user to take screen shot on browser from some specific content when visiting my site?

Tags: jquery-plugins, laravel-7

My client want to prevent user to take screen shot from browser if one visit on his site. But as per my understanding I can't prevent user to do this. If it is possible way then I can make my client happy. Is there anything I can do? as some stuff he want to show to only paid customers.

Comment: You will blow your client's mind when you introduce them to the concept of cameras being built into phones. And the fact that users can *remember* things that are displayed to them - two separate means of "copying" what's shown on a webpage that disabling screenshotting (even if it were possible) wouldn't prevent.

Comment: yes that i already told to him, but thing is there are may be some more technique to do this, but he want to prevent from students of competition level not from hackers and we can't. but for normal user we can.@Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: for the camera you are talking about i found a solution is i will overlay user id on content if that user leaks that content he will get banned from that site for future uses we can't prevent 100% from leak content but we can do this.

Comment: Couldn't the user just crop out the watermark or edit it out?

Comment: Dear @NickMcCurdy this is the way we can't stop that user but we can prevent by blocking that user.

Comment: You know @halfer people at this platform from various region of the world. and every body can't speak perfect english like you. i know you might be very good at this point but this is not the solution and you have reputation to comment means not you have the riot to demoralize some one by asking in their language if you can't able to provide solution then skip and try to write novel or start some english tutorial channel

Comment: @Prahsant: think of it is as a favour, and you will be much happier. Stack Overflow does take a bit of getting used to, and it is surely not for everyone. I advocate reading the [help] when you have a moment.